# Is there a way to specify a library name in Incisive using command line interface?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, system-verilog, hdl, cadence

In Modelsim I can specify a library name to be used, for example:

```
vlib MyPersonalLib
vcom -work MyPersonalLib foo.vhd
vsim MyPersonalLib.foo
```

Is there a way to do this in incisive without manipulating the hdl.var or cds.lib files?. Using -work for NCVHDL requires some prior setup of this files (ie: I get the error "logical library name WORK is bound to a bad library")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to at least create the file - cds.lib. In the cds.lib you define the mapping of the work name to a physical directory. The directory must be created before the ncvlog is invoked.

```
#cds.lib
DEFINE MyPersonalLib ./MyPersonalLib
```

then you can run with the work library from command prompt.

```
mkdir  ./MyPersonalLib

ncvlog your_file.v  -work MyPersonalLib -sv
```

You will get a warning message ( if you have not created a hdl.var file) . `*W,DLNOHV: Unable to find an 'hdl.var' file to load in.`  You can ignore it or use `-NOWARN DLNOHV` to suppress it.